# Can ergodic theorem be used here

Tags: ergodic-theory, markov-chains

Suppose I have an ergodic Markov Chain $\{X_n\}$ where $X_n$ are bounded. Now, Can I say anything on the limit

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln E\left[e^{\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i}\right]$$

I don't think we can use ergodic theorem here somehow.

Answer (score 3):

This has been covered for example in "Multiplicative ergodicity and large deviations for an irreducible Markov chain" by Balaji and Meyn. See also the earlier articles by Ney and Nummelin referenced there.

Comment: The limit as mentioned in the paper is some kind of infimum. Is there any result available where it is some kind of nice closed form ?